# different result of discrete fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform

I know that the way we calculate discrete fourier transform($x$ is the given data set):\begin{aligned}X_{k}&=\sum _{n=0}^{N-1}x_{n}\cdot e^{-i2\pi kn/N}\end{aligned}and there is no problem with this definition.

I tried this on a simple data set:\begin{aligned}x=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}\end{aligned} and i get:

\begin{aligned}X=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1+i\\0\\1-i\end{bmatrix}\end{aligned}

but when i try this in [here](https://betterexplained.com/articles/an-interactive-guide-to-the-fourier-transform/) i get $X/4$ instead of $X$.

i know that when i use the inverse i divide by the number of elements, but in that site they divided when they use DFT.

my question is: when do i divide by $N$? at DFT or at the inverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is purely a matter of convention. Have a look at [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/31984/4298) and its answers over at DSP.SE. You can also use the scaling constant $1/\sqrt{N}$ for both the transform and the inverse transform. In that case the DFT becomes a [unitary transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#The_unitary_DFT).